# What is happening to my knockdown ceiling texture?

Tags: repair, ceiling, texture

In my bathroom, I have some slow-pealing (over the last decade) knockdown texture. I'm not certain what caused it to begin with (was there when we purchased the house), but I'd like to get it fixed. Is this something that can be "touched up", or am I looking at a bigger job like scraping all existing texture off and reapplying?

I'm speculating that it might have been some water damage as there is some discolouration and it looks like it was touched-up a bit.

[image: slow pealing knockdown texture]
[image]

Comment: That's drywall right?    Looks like it is just torn off.    Do you have this happening everywhere?

Comment: It does look like moisture/water stain in the first picture.  Any pipe/roof leaks should have done more damage by now, so high humidity in the room is possible cause.

Answer (score 2):

The texture is sprayed onto the drywall then lightly troweled to make the "Lace" texture. Then it is painted when fully dry.

Since the surface is painted, the humidity in a bathroom should not effect it.
However it could have been a repair from a leak above that was done without the drywall being fully dried out.  This can also happen if the repair was done without the surface being clean and free of drywall dust oils and other contaminants.

To repair:

Scrape off any loose patches. Be sure the surfaces are dry and clean, even the perimeter around the area of repair, you will be spraying or dabbing new texture on there and it needs to stick.

For small repairs it is sometimes easier to just dab on some drywall compound randomly with a sponge and trowel it out. ( This may be your best bet if you only have the 2 spots) Or buy a can of knockdown spray.

Test spray on a piece of cardboard or old plywood or drywall to get the pattern close, or dab on some compound.  ( It doesn't have to be perfect. The pattern is perfectly imperfect.)
Lightly go over the patches with a wide putty knife or a foam knockdown knife.

The idea of smoothing lightly is to see how it effects the texture. You may have to go over again a bit harder. Maybe harder in some places lighter in others. (it's a learned skill that's also an art.) If it is really a mess, wipe it off with a sponge and start again.

When satisfied, let it dry for at least 24 hrs. and then paint.  At least 2 coats over the repaired areas.